# Parse IPv6 addresses from /proc/net/tcp6 (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, converters, ipv6

I'm trying to read **IPv6 addresses** from `/proc/net/tcp6` in Python 2.7. Here's a sample of the IPv6 representation that is used in `/proc/net/tcp6`:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000001000000
0000000000000000FFFF00001F00C80A
```

What I'm having trouble with is converting these to a "proper" IPv6 representation, as described on Wikipedia:

> An IPv6 address is represented as eight groups of four hexadecimal
>   digits, each group representing 16 bits (two octets). The groups are
>   separated by colons (:). An example of an IPv6 address is:
>
> ```
> 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
> ```
>
> [...] the example address can be further simplified:
>
> ```
> 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334
> ```

It seems this can be done most easily with the help of [`socket.inet_ntop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_ntop) and [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack).

However I don't know which steps exactly to take to produce the specific format that these two functions require.

Any other methods using something else from Python 2.7 stdlib are just as welcome of course.

---

Just for comparison, here's how I'm doing it right now for **IPv4 addresses** that are read from `/proc/net/tcp`:

```
>>> addr = '0101007F'
>>> addr = int(addr, 16)
>>> addr = struct.pack('<I', addr)
>>> addr = socket.inet_ntoa(addr)
>>> print addr
127.0.1.1
```

Unfortunately `inet_ntoa` doesn't support IPv6 addresses and you have to use `inet_ntop(AF_INET6, packed_ipv6)` instead.

However I don't know how to convert those strings above to a `in6_addr` struct using the `struct.pack` function.

Comment: There is a standard, _[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952)_. It does not exactly match what Wikipedia tells you. The two zero words in the middle should be replaced with a double colon (`::`).

Comment: Thanks for the note, that's actually what I had in mind, which is specified further in that section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Representation

Comment: Also, note the requirement of lower-case characters. What you are getting right now has upper-case characters, so you will need to convert them to lower-case.

Comment: I'll probably need to convert that string to decimal anyway (`int(addr, 16)`), so such conversion to lowercase will be premature.

Comment: Is this the strange word order? https://serverfault.com/questions/592574/why-does-proc-net-tcp6-represents-1-as-1000

Comment: Yes, that's why I have to use `struct.pack('<I', addr)` for IPv4 as well. Notice the `<` which means little endian: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that works, and handles native endianness automatically:

```
def ipv6(addr):
    addr = addr.decode('hex')
    addr = struct.unpack('>IIII', addr)
    addr = struct.pack('@IIII', *addr)
    addr = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, addr)
    return addr
```

Sample:

```
>>> ipv6('00000000000000000000000001000000')
'::1'
>>> ipv6('B80D01200000000067452301EFCDAB89')
'2001:db8::123:4567:89ab:cdef'
```

Steps:

1. the address is converted to byte string (`decode('hex')`),
2. split into 4 slices, maintaining the byte order as it is (`>IIII`),
3. repacked, with each slice being converted to native byte order (`@IIII`),
4. passed to `socket.inet_ntop`, which finally produces the proper IPv6 representation

On [systems that use little endian](https://serverfault.com/questions/592574/why-does-proc-net-tcp6-represents-1-as-1000), the byte string will be converted from `DCBA-HGFE-LKJI-PONM` to `ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP`. See `struct` module's [byte order notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

---

An alternative to the `unpack` & `pack` part, but twice as slow on my system, and it doesn't automatically handle native endianness (here little endian is assumed):

```
addr = ''.join(addr[i:i+4][::-1] for i in range(0, 16, 4))
```

Comment: Python3 UPDATE:

The conversion of hex to byte string has to be done using [binascii.a2b_hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from ipaddress import ip_address

components = [line[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(line), 4)]
ipv6_string = ":".join(components)
print(ip_address(ipv6_string))
```

Comment: I realized now that this will only work for Python 3. But the `ipaddress` has been backported to 2.6+ and should be available through `pip`.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. For example, [netstat.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/netstat.c#l1133) (which also reads `/proc/net/`) splits addresses into 4 parts of 8 chars, puts them into an `in6_addr` type of struct, pass it to `inet_ntop`... But I'm not familiar enough with C or its libs to say what is actually going on in that piece of code.